# How to get the image size details from size name in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, size

in WooCommerce or in WordPress in general we have size names like: `thumbnail`, `woocommerce_thumbnail`, `woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail` ...

How to get the size width and height just from the size name ?

I mean exactly the contrary of [Get image's size name from it's dimension](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/243446/get-images-size-name-from-its-dimension)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the WooCommerce dedicated function `wc_get_image_size( $size_name )` like:

```
$sizes = array('thumbnail', 'woocommerce_thumbnail', 'woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail');

echo '<ul>';
foreach( $sizes as $size_name ) {
    extract( wc_get_image_size( $size_name ) );

    echo '<li>Size "'. $size_name .'" ( width: '. $width .'px | height: '.$height.'px | crop: '.$crop.' )</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

This will display in a list for each size name, the width, height and crop values.

You can use `print_r()` to visualize the array of values from a defined size name like:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r( wc_get_image_size( 'woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail' ), true ) . '</pre>';
```

You can also see all sizes details in [`wc_get_image_size()` function source code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.1.0/includes/wc-core-functions.php#L916-L998).